# What is the difference between "use a fun” and “have a fun”?

Tags: phrase-usage

What is the difference between "use a fun” and “have a fun”?
Here is a example of “use a fun” I found

“We could use a little fun in the sun, don’t you think?

Comment: You should supply an example of "use a fun" too.

Comment: If you substitute "have a" for "use a" in your example, I would say that the meaning hasn't changed. Just maybe "use" is more common in AmE and "have" is prefered in BrE, but that's just a guess. So, please give two examples where you think the meaning is different.

Comment: "use fun" is very rare in use, i think.

Comment: have a little fun versus use a little fun. You need to use the entire idiom in your question.

Answer (score 1):

"A fun" isn't correct, but "a little fun" is possible. (*A little,* of course, meaning 'a small amount of, a short time of')

So in the context, "have fun" means "enjoy oneself" so, "We could have a little fun" means "It is possible for us to enjoy ourselves."

But "use" means "benefit from".  So, "We could use a little fun" means "We would benefit from enjoying ourselves."

Comment: _A little_, of course, meaning 'a small amount of, a short time of'.